# Is it possible to run calculations while aggregating in Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

In StandardSQL, is it possible to run operations on each row during the grouping process? I'm not sure if I'm even asking the right question. Here's an example.

Let's say I have 3 rows like this:

```
| move_id | item_id | quantity | value |
|---------|---------|----------|-------|
| 1       | 1       | 10       | 100   |
| 1       | 2       | 20       | 150   |
| 1       | 3       | 30       | 200   |
```

I now want to group the table by move_id, summing values based on the proportion of each row's quantity to the minimum quantity.

For example the minimum quantity is 10, and row 2 has a quantity of 20, which means it's value should be cut in half before summing. Row 3 has a quantity of 30, which means it's value should be cut to a third before summing.

So my final value column should be 100 + (150 / 2) + (200 / 3) = 241.67.

My result should be:

```
| move_id | quantity | value  |
|---------|----------|--------|
| 1       | 10       | 241.67 |
```

The query should be something like:

```sql
SELECT ANY_VALUE(move_id) AS move_id, MIN(quantity) AS quantity, SUM([THIS IS MY QUESTION, WHAT GOES HERE?]) as value FROM table GROUP BY move_id;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The somewhat difficult part of your query is that you want to aggregate, but the sum you have in mind itself requires the result of an aggregation - the minimum `quantity` per each `move_id` group.  One option here would be to first generate the min `quantity` in a CTE, then aggregate that CTE using your logic.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MIN(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY move_id) min_quantity
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    move_id,
    MIN(quantity) AS quantity,
    SUM(value * min_quantity / quantity) AS value
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    move_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: The above demo uses SQL Server, but the SQL used is ANSI compliant, and should also run on BigQuery without any issues.

Also, if your version of BigQuery does not support cte, then you may just inline the code contained inside the CTE as as a subquery.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try. Any chance you can try to explain in words what you're doing? I had been looking at the `OVER` clause as a way to do this, but couldn't figure it out. What is the query doing?

Comment: @flyingL123 I added an explanation to my answer.  What I posted is just one way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and does all in one shot

```
#standardSQL
SELECT move_id, 
  MIN(quantity) AS quantity, 
  SUM(value/quantity) * MIN(quantity) AS value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY move_id
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row move_id quantity    value    
1   1       10          241.66666666666669
```

As you can see here - instead of splitting calculation/aggregation inside query, you can rather transform your formula such like below

- 100 + (150 / 2) + (200 / 3)
- (100 * 10 / 10 + (150 * 10 / 20) + (200 * 10 / 30)
- ((100 / 10 + (150 / 20) + (200 / 30)) * 10
- SUM(value / quantity) * MIN(quantity)

so, you ended up with just simple aggregation "in one shot"

Comment: This is so incredibly brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: lol. agree. you might want to accept this answer instead then?

Comment: I feel like the first answer that answered my question should remain accepted. Yours doesn't make the other one any less correct. Not sure the proper SO etiquette on this one, you probably know better than me. I did give you an upvote though!

Comment: Using this method, is there any way to ensure that MIN(quantity) > 0, and if it's not, set the value = 0? I have tried a case statement or IF function like this: `IF(MIN(quantity) > 0, SUM(value / quantity) * MIN(quantity), 0)`, but it doesn't seem to work. I still get division by 0 errors.

Comment: I also tried `IF(COUNTIF(quantity = 0) > 0, 0, SUM(value / quantity) * MIN(quantity))` but that doesn't seem to work either. Division by 0 error.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of CTEs, you can use [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subquery) to fetch minimum quantity for every `move_id` separately. And, then utilize them in the main query, to compute the sum:

```
SELECT t.move_id,
       dt.min_quantity,
       Sum(t.value / ( t.quantity / dt.min_quantity )) AS value
FROM   your_table AS t
       JOIN (SELECT move_id,
                    Min(quantity) AS min_quantity
             FROM   your_table
             GROUP  BY move_id) AS dt
         ON dt.move_id = t.move_id
GROUP  BY t.move_id
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f0423/1)**

Comment: Recent versions of BigQuery [do support common table expressions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause).